# How to pass an array of data from the client side to req.body of an axios post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, axios

I'm trying to send user data collected in my front end using an ajax call to an axios post request I have set up in my back end. I have a few parameters that require an array of data to be sent back. When I console.log(req.body) in the back end, the data matches up with the variables I have set to req.body, except for the variables that are supposed to take in the array, which are timestamp, values, reason, notes.

```
postModel: async (req, res) => {
    
        const { analyst, building_number, commodity_tag, meter, timestamp, values, reason, notes } = req.body
   
        console.log(req.body)
     
        try {

           const headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'authorizationToken': token.token
            }

   
             const postdata = JSON.stringify({
                'analyst': analyst,
                'building_number': building_number,
                'commodity_tag': commodity_tag,
                'meter': meter,
                'data': {
                    'timestamp': [timestamp],
                    'value': [values],
                    'reason': [reason],
                    'notes': [notes]
                }
            })

            const postModel = process.env.POST_API_URL

            const response = await axios.post(postModel, postdata, {
                headers: headers
            })
           
            return res.json(response.data)

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message)
            return res.json(error)
        }
```

This is req.body logged to the console after data is sent back using the front end ajax call. The four variables that are supposed to be arrays come back in a weird string format, and when I try to use the variable, the value is null so nothing gets passed to the axios data. Or for example if I try to console.log(timestamp) it comes back as undefined, but if I console.log(meter) it gives me the correct value. How do I stop the array data from being sent to my backend in a string format and have it placed into my req.body variable so I can use it in the axios post data?

```
[Object: null prototype] {
  analyst: 'email@email.com',
  building_number: '0227',
  commodity_tag: 'S',
  meter: '2032',
  'timestamp[]': [ '2021-10-05', '2021-10-06', '2021-10-07', '2021-10-08' ],
  'values[]': [ '5830', '6119', '5830', '5830' ],
  'reason[]': [ 'Investigate', 'Investigate', 'Investigate', 'Investigate' ],
  'notes[]': [
    'Testing backend',
    'Testing backend',
    'Testing backend',
    'Testing backend'
  ]
}
```

This is the front end ajax call. I push data into the four empty arrays and then set those variables in the data values down below.

```
        let notes = []
        let reason = []
        let values = []
        let timestamp = []
          $.ajax({
                url: '/postGateway',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    analyst: analyst,
                    building_number: building_number,
                    commodity_tag: commodity_tag,
                    meter: meter,
                    timestamp: timestamp,
                    values: values,
                    reason: reason,
                    notes: notes

                },
             
            })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I just had to stringify the data on the front end, and then parse it on the back end. Like this:

Front end ajax call. I JSON.stringify the array data.

```
 $.ajax({
                url: '/postGateway',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    analyst: analyst,
                    building_number: building_number,
                    commodity_tag: commodity_tag,
                    meter: meter,
                    timestamp: JSON.stringify(timestamp),
                    values: JSON.stringify(values),
                    reason: JSON.stringify(reason),
                    notes: JSON.stringify(notes)

                },
})
```

And then I parse the req.body variables in the back end. And now my data submits perfectly!

```
const postdata = JSON.stringify({
                'analyst': analyst,
                'building_number': building_number,
                'commodity_tag': commodity_tag,
                'meter': meter,
                'data': {
                    'timestamp': JSON.parse(timestamp),
                    'value': JSON.parse(values),
                    'reason': JSON.parse(reason),
                    'notes': JSON.parse(notes)
                }
            })
```